# How can I strip an open source app of trackers?

Tags: java, android, open-source, privacy

I want to use an open source app (https://github.com/NYRDS/remixed-dungeon), but the amount od tracking the app does is something else. The GPL (under which the app is licenced) allows me to change this. Is there a tool or a guide to do just that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a bit of development experience, Java and Gradle in this case.

Then I would load the app project into Android Studio and compile it. You have to have no compile errors.

Then check the `build.gradle` files for ad libraries (e.g. entries starting with `implementation` or `androidImplementation`). Comment them one-by-one out and after commenting out one check for compile errors where code from this libraries is used.

Comment out also the code with errors because the library is no longer present. Repeat until all errors are fixed.